# JQuery Data Tables secondary sort not working properly

Tags: jquery, sorting, salesforce, datatables, visualforce

I have a data table set up on a visualforce page. Here is my code:

This is the custom sort extension:

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "hybrid-asc": function(x, y) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(x)) && !isNaN(parseInt(y))) {
            x = parseInt(x);
            y = parseInt(y);
        }
        return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
    },
    "hybrid-desc": function(x, y) {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt(x)) && !isNaN(parseInt(y))) {
            x = parseInt(x);
            y = parseInt(y);
        }
        return ((x < y) ? 1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
    }
});
```

Here is my data table code:

```
$(".tablesorterResJob").dataTable( {
    //"bSort": true,
    "aaSorting": [[1,'asc'],[5,'asc']],
    "sScrollY": "200px",
    "sScrollX": "100%",
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sWidth": "30px" },
        { "bSortable": true },
        null,
        null,
        null,
        { "bSortable": true, "sType": "hybrid" },
        null,
        null
    ],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "bJQueryUI": true, 
    "iDisplayLength": 10,
    "bLengthChange": false
} )
```

So I want to sort primarily by column 1 and then sort by column 5.

Here is a screen shot of my data: http://s7.postimg.org/icwm2pfsb/results.png

The distance column (column 5) is not being sorted properly. What's weird is that if I switch which column is the primary column (`"aaSorting": [[5,'asc'],[1,'asc']]`), it works fine.

Can anyone shed some light on this?